# Is there a best practice to make a package PEP-561 compliant?

Tags: python, setuptools, mypy

I'm writing a Python project which is published as a package to a pypi-like repository (using `setuptools` and `twine`). I use type hints in my code.

The issue is, when importing the package from a different project and running `mypy`, I get the following error:
`error: Skipping analyzing 'XXX': found module but no type hints or library stubs`

As I understand, I got this error because my package was not compliant with https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/ .

After some searching online, I didn't find a way that was not manual to add the required files to the package.

I resorted to writing my own code to:

1. Run `stubgen` to create stub files.
2. Create `py.typed` files in every directory.
3. Collect all the created files in a `dict` in `package_data` field in the `setup.py` file.

This code solved the issue and `mypy` runs without errors. But this feels very wrong to me. Is there a standard tool for making a package PEP-561 compliant? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Have you tried skipping step 1 and simplifying step 3 so you only include the `py.typed` file in the `package_data` field? If there's a `py.typed` file and no stub files, type checkers such as mypy are supposed to analyze your source code directly to grab type hints.

Comment: That's a nice optimization, but ultimately I still have to write custom code. Also, generating stubs is the easy part, since there's a tool for that.

Comment: I don't think you need to be writing any custom code? You should need to create only a single `py.typed` file at the top-level package and tweak your `setup.py` file once to hard-code the path to the new file. The presence of the `py.typed` file in the top-level package will imply that all subpackages must be analyzed by the type checker. Taking a closer look at your step two, it seems what you're doing instead is adding a `py.typed` file in each directory? If so, that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Directions on how to configure this in `pyproject.toml` are hard to find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76073605/add-py-typed-as-package-data-with-setuptools-in-pyproject-toml

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As mentioned before, You need to add the `py.typed` in the package folder of the module.
You also need to add that file to the [setup.py package_data](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data) - otherwise the file would not be part of the package when You deploy it.

I personally put the type annotations in the code and dont create extra stub files - but that is only possible from python 3.4 upwards. If You want to make python2.7 compatible code, You can not use inline type annotation - in that case You can use stub files.

If You want to type annotate a third party library, You can write a *.pyi file for the functions You use for that library. That can be a bit tricky, because MYPY must only find that *.pyi file ONCE in the MYPY Path.

So I handle it that way :

for local testing, the MYPY path is set to a directory were I collect all the 3rd party stubs,
for testing on travis, I have a subdirectory in the package with the stubs needed for that module to test it on travis, and set the mypy path accordingly.

Comment: Creating the file at the root of the main package (`<package-folder>/py.typed`) or adding `include <path/to>/py.typed` in a new line to `MANIFEST.in` file in the directory will also ensure that the `py.typed` file is part of the package.

Answer (score 16):

The solution was to add one `py.typed` file to the root of the main package. This forces mypy to analyze the types.

Comment: And importantly, add the `py.typed` file to the package_data in setup.py or to the MANIFEST.in file.