# Add py.typed as package data with setuptools in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml, typed

From what I read, to make sure that the typing information of your code is distributed alongside your code for linters to read, the `py.typed` file should be part of your distribution.

I find answers for how to add these to [setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034060/1150683) but it is not clear to me 1. whether it should be included in pyproject.toml (using setuptools), 2. if so, how it should be added.

Scouring their github repository, it seems that this is [not added automatically](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3136) so the question remains how I should add it to my pyproject.toml. I found this general discussion about [`package_data`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#package-data) but it includes reference to `include_package_data` and a `MANIFEST.in` and it gets confusing from there what should go where.

Tl;dr: how should I include `py.typed` in pyproject.toml when using setuptools?

Comment: Show a [mre], then we can help you fix it. -- Basically adding an entry in `MANIFEST.in` and enabling `include_package_data` should be enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you should add `py.typed` to your package's source folder (same level as `__init__.py`). This informs type checkers, like `mypy`, that your package supports typing. See [PEP 561](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/).

Here is an example of what is needed in `pyproject.toml`. Replace `pkgname` with the name of your package.

```ini
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"pkgname" = ["py.typed"]
```

It is worth noting package discovery using:

```ini
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

seems to be required, alas `package-data` wouldn't have any effect, as explained in `setuptools` docs: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#package-data

Comment: Thank Vanroy and Hostetter that *someone* documented this.