# py.typed does not be included when use pyproject.toml

Tags: python, build, mypy

I am publishing my package with `mypy` supported. Unfortunately, I can't bundle `py.typed` which is blank file to py package. Here is my directory structure from my [repository](https://github.com/elcolie/AGA8-python).

I have followed the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76073605/add-py-typed-as-package-data-with-setuptools-in-pyproject-toml), but does not work.

```bash
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── aga8
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── detail.cpython-311.pyc
│   ├── detail.py
│   ├── py.typed
│   └── tests.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.cfg

2 directories, 9 files
```

`pyproject.toml`

```bash
[project]
name = "aga8-python"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
  { name="Sarit Ritwirune", email="sarit@appsmiths.com" },
]
description = "American Gas Association Report No.8"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.8"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[tool.poetry]
packages = [
    {include = "aga8/py.typed"}
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/elcolie/AGA8-python"

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"aga8" = ["py.typed"]

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["aga8"]
```

**Question:**
How to include `py.typed` which is blank file in `aga8` packaged directory?

**Temporary Solution:**
I follow `humanize` repository. I think it add `py.typed` at last before publish.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this lines.

```bash
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["aga8"]
```

Then run with `python -m build`

Will see this line in the output.

```
copying aga8/py.typed -> aga8-python-0.0.1/aga8
```